# Coefficients of a particular polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Let $f$ be the polynomial obtained by taking the terms $1$, $x^3$, $x^6$, $x^9$, ... $x^k$,... for $k\equiv 0,3,6$ (mod 9) in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ with the corresponding coefficients. That is,
$$f(x) = \sum_{k\leq n, k \equiv 0,3,6} \binom{n}{k} x^k$$
What are the (complex) roots of $f$?

Comment: What have you tried?   Are we guaranteed that $n$ is a multiple of $3$? If not, you have three cases to consider. If you don't have any other ideas, often trying small $n$ can show you a pattern.

Comment: If $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/3}$ then $f(x)=\frac{(1+x)^n+(1+\zeta x)^n+(1+\zeta^2 x)^n}{3}$, though I don't see how to use this to find the roots.

Comment: $n$ is arbitrary. I've considered the case $n$ a multiple of 9 explicitly but gotten nowhere. I've also done $1\leq n \leq 9$ but did not detect a pattern.

Comment: You should add the results of that investigation to your question, using the edit button below.  It will save others from repeating the work and show what you are thinking about and what tools you have available.

Comment: Do you have reasons to expect "nice" (closed form) roots in general, or is it just curiosity? FWIW for $n$ a multiple of $6$ you can reduce it to a polynomial of degree $\frac{n}{6}$ in $z=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}$.

Comment: Just curiosity. I had some vague hope of relating it to cyclotomic polynomials. It's certainly believable that there is no nice expression